# Python - lambda comparator function to compare on a custom order

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

I am stepping through a Python package's code to attempt to understand what it is doing so that I can modify it, but I'm getting confused on one step.

The code has the line:

```
get_key = lambda r: (r.CHROM, r.POS)
```

which is used to order a list based on `r.CHROM` and `r.POS` (I think at least thats what it's doing).
Given my particular case, `r.CHROM` is a `str` data type which can be any numeric values from `1-22`, as well as alpha characters, `X`, `Y`, and `MT` in that order of sorting priority.

The issue is when this lambda function is used to sort, it sorts on alphanumeric and comes out in the order `1,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,2,20,21,22, ...` which is obviously incorrect from what I want.

Is it possible to modify this lambda function to provide a custom comparison priority or hierarchy, so that my resulting list comes out as `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,X,Y,MT`???

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated! I'm at a loss here.

Comment: I'm guessing the `151,6` in your resulting list is a typo? Did you mean `15,16`?

Comment: @Kevin Oops, yes. Corrected, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step is to ensure that you are sorting `r.CHROM` as an integer, not a string:

```
get_key = lambda r: (int(r.CHROM), r.POS)
```

However, this clearly fails when `r.CHROM` has one of its three non-numeric values. The trick is to treat those as "virtual" integer values of 23, 24, and 25, respectively.

```
chrom_num_values = {'X': 23, 'Y': 24, 'MT': 25}
get_key = lambda r: (chrom_num_values.get(r.CHROM) or int(r.CHROM),
                     r.POS)
```

Comment: This is still going to evaluate `int(r.CHROM)` (and so raise a `ValueError`) for those non-numeric values.

Comment: Right. We'll take advantage of `None` being treated as a False value instead.

Comment: This is missing a left parenthesis, but aside from that it is beautiful and simple. Answer accepted and +1. And I learned something more about lambdas. Thanks @chepner.

Comment: Yeah, I had an extra right-paren, actually. Gone now.